# Run ansible in docker

Tags: docker, ansible

Is it possible to bring 4-5 containers with docker-compose then run ansible roles?(Ansible can be  installed onto one container or run from my local pc to a containers) So basically those 4-5 containers will be my target hosts.

Comment: https://www.ansible.com/blog/testing-ansible-roles-with-docker are you looking for this

Comment: You could, but I wouldn’t call it a best practice...usually once you bring a container up with `docker-compose up` all of its software is already installed (in its image) and it is already configured, and there shouldn’t be a need to manage it by hand with Ansible, `docker-compose exec`, or anything else.

Comment: @David Maze Why I need this is because I would like to install Pretty Complicated application with control plan and managed services. I don't want to do it manually

Comment: @Akshay barahate no, Docker containers must be my target hosts

Answer (score 7):

Sure, it's possible.  You would target an **image**, not a **container**, by running Ansible as part of your Dockerfile.  For example, something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# Install prerequisities for Ansible
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-nacl python3-pip libffi-dev

# Install ansible
RUN pip3 install ansible

# Copy your ansible configuration into the image
COPY my_ansible_project /ansible

# Run ansible to configure things
RUN ansible-playbook /ansible/playbook.yml
```

Note also that the [packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html) tool can (a) build docker images and (b) has an ansible provisioner.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you. My problem is that in my main playbook I'm calling 6 different roles to ADMIN server then to MANAGED servers same roles based on tags and when expression and extra vars. I don't know how to do this with Docker files. After dockerizing them I wanna run them in K8s @larsks

Answer (score 7):

You can change the connection type of Ansible from SSH to Docker using `ansible_connection: docker` in your inventory file or `--connection docker` from the command line. This will allow you to use Docker hostnames as inventory. The documentation can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. This changes everything!